# Split text into separate cells onclick JS

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, split, html-table

I have text input from the user that needs to split into table cells `onclick`.

Eg. For the sentence "The five boxing wizards jump quickly" in a table cell, I can click on the word "boxing" and the text will split into two cells with "The five" in one cell and "boxing wizards jump quickly" in another cell.

The user should be able to click "wizards" and "jump" and the sentence will be split into three cells, "The five boxing | wizards | jump quickly." Multiple clicks will mean multiple cells

Here is the code I have right now:
(Splits into array, adds spans with unique id/index, and writes as innerHTML. When a word is clicked it logs the index/id of the specific word/span)

```js
function pageText() {
    let pageText = "The five boxing wizards jump quickly";
    pageTextSection.innerHTML = "";

    let textArray = pageText.split(" "); 
    textArray.forEach((item, index) => {
        let line = ` <span class='sectionBreakSpan' id='${index}' onclick='splitSection(this.id)' >${item}</span> `;
        pageTextSection.innerHTML += line;
    })
}

function splitSection(index) {
    let arr = pageTwoTextSection.innerText.split(" ")
    console.log(index)  
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="pageTextRow">
    <td>
      <p id="pageTextSection"></p>
    </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

This currently logs the index number of the clicked word. The first word is 0, second is 1...  But I need the string to **split** on the clicked word and move to a new table cell. If I click on the word with index of 3, then 3 and on should be in the next cell.

Comment: You never call the functions in the code snippet. `localStorage` doesn't work in the Stack Snippet sandbox, can you replace that with a hard-coded string?

Comment: Use `document.getElementById(index).innerText` to get the text of the element that was clicked on.

Comment: Instead of passing `this.id` to `splitSection()`, why not just pass `this` so it doesn't have to call another function to get the element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed a bit logic to for split text.

hope it help you.

```js
  const text = `The five boxing wizards jump quickly`;
  const arrayText = text.split(` `);
  const pageText = document.getElementById(`pageText`);
  const btn = document.getElementById(`btn`);
  const table = document.getElementById(`table`);

  arrayText.forEach((txt, index) => {
    pageText.insertAdjacentHTML(
      `beforeend`,
      `<span id=` + index + `>` + txt + `</span> `
    );
  });

  let slected = [];
  pageText.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    const id = e.target.id;
    if (slected.includes(id)) {
      e.target.style.color = "black";
      slected = slected.filter((i) => i != id);
    } else {
      slected.push(id);
      e.target.style.color = "red";
    }
  });

  btn.addEventListener("click", function () {
    table.innerHTML = "";
    slected.sort((a, b) => a - b);
    let firstIndex = 0;
    slected.forEach((item, index) => {
      let txt = arrayText.slice(firstIndex, item).join(" ");
      table.insertAdjacentHTML(`beforeend`, `<tr>` + txt + `</tr>`);
      firstIndex = item;
    });
    table.insertAdjacentHTML(
      `beforeend`,
      `<tr>` + arrayText.slice(firstIndex, text.length).join(" ") + `</tr>`
    );
  });
```

```html
<div style="cursor: pointer" id="pageText"></div>
<button id="btn">Split</button>
<table id="table"></table>
```

Comment: This is super helpful, my only question is if there is a way to make _any_ number of splits like this. Let's say the user wants to split the text into 3 cells, or 4, or 16. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: When user click "boxing", it will split "The five" and "boxing wizards jump quickly" then user can click again in "boxing wizards jump quickly" and split this sentence again?

Example, 
| The five boxing wizards jump quickly |
1. Click "boxing "
| The five | boxing wizards jump quickly |
2. Click "wizards "
| The five | boxing | wizards jump quickly |

or
user should take action only one time to split sentence to multiple cell.

Comment: The user should be able to click "wizards" and "jump" and the sentence will be split into three cells, "The five boxing | wizards | jump quickly." Multiple clicks will mean multiple cells.

Comment: I try to updated my code follow your request already, please check it's follow your request or not.

Comment: Almost works perfectly, my only issue is that the txt doesn't end up in the <tr> tags but outside of them.

Comment: As a solution to that issue, I changed your code from using HTML strings to creating nodes. Instead of  `table.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<tr>' + txt + '</tr>');`
   I used `const tr = table.insertRow();
            const td = tr.insertCell();
            td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(txt));`